# Extract image data from EPS

Tags: image, extract, eps

I have an [encapsulated PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulated_PostScript) file which appears to only wrap an image file.

Is there a tool to extract the image data from it?

Comment: Can you point us to a place we could download it and try?

Answer (score 4):

"convert" will use ghostscript to render the eps, and then continues with the rendered bitmap; this makes it difficult to get the original image back, in most cases you get a re-sampled image.

I understand that you want the image out in the original resolution. I haven't got a direct route for you. However, for getting images from pdf files, you can use pdfimages. Assuming you are running this on a Linux box (or with cygwin)

```
ps2pdf file.eps
pdfimages file.pdf basename
```

This gives you a basename.pnm or basename.ppm file. Use convert to get it to jpeg or png. If you had a lossy format (jpg) in the .eps, this would re-code the jpg, so some additional loss is unavoidable.

```
convert basename.pnm file.jpg
```

or

```
convert basename.ppm file.png
```

p.s. The  file from the question is no longer available. However, this answer might still be of interest to others.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick can do that:

```
convert file.eps file.jpg
```

or you can do

```
convert file.eps file.png
convert file.eps file.tif
```

ImageMagick is available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

[image: example image]

Comment: I would like to preserve the original data from the EPS file. How do I know the embedded file format?

Comment: I do not understand :-) Which data do you mean? Surely you have the original image data in the EPS file already?

Comment: Indeed. It can be embedded as JPG, PNG, or a number of other formats. I would like to extract that exact data. With `convert`, I have to specify the output format unconditionally of how it is stored in the EPS.

Comment: I still don't get it :-) If you subsequently need the data in a different format, just extract it to that format as I showed. If you want to look in the EPS file for some reason, you can use `strings file.eps | more` and you will see all the gory details.

Comment: I'm under the impression that EPS can encapsulate a number of different image files. I would like to extract whatever image file is stored in the EPS, without losing information. If a PNG is encapsulated and I `convert` into JPG, I lose information. I do not want that.

Comment: My point is that you don't lose information because you stil have the EPS file and if you later wish to extract it a different way, you can.

Comment: This is not extraction, this is conversion. The size of the output file is very different -> this is not taking part of the original data.