# Extract an embedded image from an .eps file

Tags: encoding, decode, eps

My question is simiar to this one: [Extract image data from EPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166187/extract-image-data-from-eps)
..but i want to extract the raw image data from the embedded bitmap, instead of converting the `.eps` file to a different image file.

EPS header info:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: Adobe Photoshop Version 6.0.1
%%Title: TORESEN&CO.eps
%%CreationDate: 03.04.06 08:53
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 890 510
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 889.92 510.24
%%SuppressDotGainCompensation
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
%%EndSetup
%ImageData: 1854 1063 8 3 1 1854 1 "beginimage"
...
```

I have read this Tek-Tips Forums thread - [Extract a jpeg from an eps](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1049335) - which states that the image data is an [Ascii85](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85) encoded string between two `%%BeginBinary`/`%%EndBinary` tags. I find the tags in my file, but the data doesn't look like Ascii85:

```
...
%%BeginBinary:    7883219
beginimage
ïííèèéëïñëêêççèèëêëéíñððëéëççððëíñðíëéèëéæéêêéëëêíðññññðððèèêðéåçéçêëìïðîìíéëéêëíðíððííëæííèééíðññíëëííííëíìèððëëíïðîðíðíëëíëñððððëêëéëëëðëíëëííëéëðíæêéíñíííðëééçëëëïðíððíìíñíëïðíäëêïñðíìëëëëêíëëéëíðññíêìðëííëëëíííðíññññððíííéêççìíêíìíðíëííïéñðñíëïððððððíððëíëðëëííðíëëííêìñìëêääëíðëèðððñðíëëêéèíëëëééêëëëííëëèëëëëíëííííëëííðïñïëëëëëéëëííññïððíðñëðèééêëíððíêêèìíííìëêëíííëêéíçêêíððëêçåææëíèëééðíëëëêëëëëëéêëèíëéêéíëëëéççççêåëëëêéëíëíëêæíñëëëëèíííííëëííðñííëëçëëéêêéíðððíííñðíðíéëçêéêëëëëííððíìïíììíéééééëëëññññññèííìííìððííðìííåêëððìëëðððíëííêííéïíëéíðïððéííïëíííðëëçççíñìííéëëðñððííííððñëçííííðïíðððñðíêæäçëëííçäêéëëëêééíððññðíðñëêëíéððñðíííðððïððððëèèçêêëððëéëðíðñðëííðëçêëêíïññííëíðííëêèííððíëíððññíðíððìíåäëëëðíííííðíðïññíëëëêêëðñííííëêëëñíòïðñððííëëëëçëèçççêéêèáãåãëíííëííêêëçíëæêêëêëðíííëíííëëëëëêêêçæêçääææêèíëëêëëíëêëëêëëííëëíêçåçêêêííêëíëíêæãæëíëëííðêëííêëêêêëíëíìíææéëëêèêéëëçêíëêêëççêëéèéëêèéíñððëëëíêëðððëëéêíêêíííëçæêëëêçêèëêëëëííëëíëííðííðíïðëðñíëííððíëéðëëëëíííññðñíêæçççëëëëíëæäèèíéêçêèëëíííëëíëëçççêåçêççèèçåëíéëëëëëëëêæëæíííëíëíííððêçççêçêêæåçëíëéêêçççääêêæêëëéççéëêíðííñëëíðíêçççêèëëëíëëëëëëêííëíçääçííëæéíëíëëðêæèêííðññððëçëëëêêëêëíëðííííííëëíííëíëêåæêçåëëëëéííëííííííêééêëêðëððëëíííëðííðñëìððññíððëðéçêëíëêêíðìëëíêëëíéççéèëíëëèëëíìèðëëêççëëëëíðêéðððíêëëêéêçéìíéëëëëêëêêíëííðòððíìíëëèëíñòòðëðííííðéíêëëèêëêëééëêçêêíñðííëññéíðïëêêççëëêåêëðëëêðëëëêéëíêêêêçåëëéêéëííëëëííêçåçêèéëíêåçæèèðëíìëíìëíðííëëëíðééëëëðééëëëçéìííííëèêæççíëëêíïëíëæêêééëêéëíêêëðííëíéëíëíæâåæëéêçêçêëìðððñîëëíëðííêççåçèêêëêíïíëëéëííëððëññííïêíìííðññðëíëííððìïíëëçáèçëèêéëéíñìíëëëííðñííêíéêéèëèççæìëëìëëëêëíëéíñòñëêëéçêåçêéííëðíìèëçêêëíëëëéìððððêçäææëìðíëëðíííëêëéæéííðíðíìëêæêëëéëíëíééêççåääêçëíëíëèééëçéçàâéèëåêëííííððëëëêêàÜãçæææçäêëíëëñðëëëëííëðëëëðïðïðððñðèééíðñððííëçëêêéëëëëêèëèëëëêêëðîëêððíéëëéêëíëëéëééëëéêïððñðçëííëëëêêëëêêéëêçåæåëëííññííëíðíëíëçëñíëëêééíëðñííëîìñññíêêççëëíêëìðñïïëìíëíïïëðñïíëêëëìçêêêìëëêíïññññïïïîëêïìæçêçêëíïïïííìñìêëíïíïïðííïííîìêíïññðñííííííííîïïíëíïñôïíïííííëññïïïëêëìëíëïííëëíííìñïðïêìíñðííïíìêçëëëñïíïïííðñíëïïíæëêññïííëëëëëíñëëëðïññíêíïëííëëëíííïíññññïïíííêêííííëííðïíëííïêñïñíñïïïïïïïðïïëíñïííðíïðñíðíëíñíëêææëíïñîïïïñóííëêêîíëëëììêíëëíííñîëííííëííííëíííïïñïëëëëëêëëííññïïïðïñëïîêêêëíïïíêêëííííííêëíííëêìííêêíïïëêçèæçíðîíììïíëëëêëíëëëêêëîíëìêìíëëëìíçççêîíëëêìëíííëêçíñëëííîíðííííëííïñððëëçëëêêêìíïïïíííñïíïíìëìëêêííëëííïïííïííííêêìêìëëëññññññîííííííïïííïíííèêëïïíëëïïïííííêííêïíëêíïïïïòííñëíííïëëçççíñííðêíëïñïïííííïïñëçíðííïñðïïïñïíêæäçëëííçäêìëëíêììíïïññïðïñëêëíêïïñïíííïïïïïïïïëëîçêêëïïëêíïíïñïíííïëçêëêíïññðíëðïííëêëðíïïíëíïïññíïíïïííææëëñïíííííïíïïññíëíëêêëïñíííííêëíñíòïïñïïííëëëëçëëçççêìêëççèäëíííëííêêëííëçêêëêëïíííëííííëëííêêêçæêçääææêëííëêëííëêëëêëííðëëíêçèçêêêðíêííëíêæéæëíííííïêëííêëêêêëíííííëæìëëêëêêëëçêíëêêëççêëìëìëêëìíñïïëëëíêëïïïëëêêíêêííííçæêëëêçêëëêëëëííëëíëííïííïíñïëïñíëííïïíëìïëëëëííðññññíêæçççëëëííëæäëìíìêçêëëëíííëëíëííççêèçêççëëçæëíìëëëíííëêæëïíííëíííííïïêçççêçêêææçëííêêêççççäêêæêëëìççìëêíïððñëëíïíêçççêëííëííëíëëëêííëíçääçííëçêíëíëëïëïëêííïññïïíçíííêêëêëíëïííííííííðííëíëêèëêçèëëëëêííëííííííêììêëêïëïïëëíííëïííïññíïïññíïïíïêçêëíëêêíïíëëíêëëðêççìëëíííîëëííîïíëêççííëëðïêêïïïíêëëêêêçìòíìëëëíêëêêííííïòïïðííëëëëíñòòïëïííííïòíêëñîêëêëìêëêçêêíñïííñññòíïïëêêççëëêèêëïëëêïíííêêëííêêêçæëëìêìíííëëëíðêçæçêëêëíêæçëìîïëííëííëíïííëëëíïììëííïììëëëçìíðííííîêæççííëêíïëíëçêêêêëêìííêêëïííííìëíëíæåèæíìêçêçêëíïïïñïíñííïííêççèíîêêëêíïíëëìíííëïïëññðíïíííííïññïëíëííïïíïíëëçéëçëëêìëìíñííëëëííïñííëíêêìîëëççëíëëíëëëêíðíêíñòñëêëêçêæçêìðíëïííîëíêêëííëëìí

... and about 7MB more of the this ...

%%EndBinary
grestore end % Image Trailer grestore
grestore % EPS grestore
```

Any idea what this data is and/or how it is encoded?